Save DateTime in mysql database based on Asia/Tehran time zone
I have a Django project where I have used a DateTime field in one of its models.
In this database field, I want to save the date and time of this moment.
Also, my database is mysql type and on the server.
First of all I have set Django settings.
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tehran'
USE_I18N = True
USE_TZ = True

Also, to be sure, I edited the database model as follows.
class Register(models.Model):
    card = models.ForeignKey(Card, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
    member = models.ForeignKey('member.Members', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)
    field = models.ForeignKey(Field, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    session_count = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tehran_tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Tehran')
        if self.start_date:
            self.start_date = self.start_date.astimezone(tehran_tz)
        if self.end_date:
            self.end_date = self.end_date.astimezone(tehran_tz)
        super(Register, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

I have also set the time zone in the database using the following command.
SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Asia/Tehran';
SET time_zone = 'Asia/Tehran';


The result of executing the following command in the database is as follows.
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'time_zone'; 

The interesting thing is that when I print the time and date in the terminal, it shows correctly, but when I save it in the database, it is saved as UTC.

This question is similar to: Timestamp from server is different than local. The question asked in post may not be pertinent . But the answer should be more than adequate.
